# Drupal hook webform using cURL submits twice

Tags: php, drupal, curl

I'm using a custom module to intercept form submits and then cURL submits the data to a 3rd party website (in this case Pardot... but I've gotten the same results in other CRMs like Marketo as well).

This all works and the data is properly submitted, but Drupal is submitting it twice. I've tried the same cURL function outside of Drupal and it only sends once, so there's something going on in Drupal causing this function to run twice I suppose.

Anyone got an idea why this is happening? Thanks!

**UPDATE:** So I did some more testing with specificity and it doesn't matter the number of forms, or specifying a single form... it always submits exactly twice.

```
function hook_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if (strstr($form['#form_id'], 'webform_client_form_')) {
    array_unshift($form['#submit'], 'hook_pardot_submit');
  }
}
/**
 * Send post data to pardot via curl
 */
function hook_pardot_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  // Values sent from form 
  $values = $form_state['values']['submitted'];

  if ( ! function_exists('curl_init')) {
   error("Curl is not setup on this PHP server and is required for this script.");
  }

  //Open cURL connection
  $ch = curl_init();
  if (curl_error($ch) != "") {
    die("Error: $error");
  }

  // Submit data to pardot
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://mypardoturl.com");
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($values,'', '&'));
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, FALSE);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);

  //Execute pardot PHP cURL
  $result = curl_exec($ch);

  //close cURL connection
  curl_close($ch);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after more debugging, it turns out the Drupal form_alter function (which was calling the submit function above) was being called twice, thus causing Pardot to get two submissions.

The reason this was happening was because the **theme name and this custom module name were the same**. Once I uninstalled the module, changed the module folder, .info and .module names to be different than the theme name, it only calls the form_alter function once.

Comment: Thanks a lot... you just saved my day!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have more than one webforms in the website? Maybe 2?

Because at the moment the function `hook_form_alter` runs with an if statement that uses 'strstr'. You should be more specific in the if statement here and use the form id of the webform with **equal operator** ("==").

Comment: I do have two webforms on the site, but appear on separate pages. I'd like to have both forms submit using cURL though, which is why I used the generic if statement. I'll try and specify it to one and see if that solves the problem, and then figure out a way to apply it to both.

Comment: Unfortunately it still submits twice.